# After adding HSTS and Xframe policies it's still not showing up in the browser. (NGINX)

Tags: nginx, xss, hsts

I am using docker to run a react app with Nginx not sure why it's not implementing the headers I added.

```
    http{
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
client_max_body_size 999M;
access_log /dev/stdout;
error_log /dev/stderr;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        server_tokens off;
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;preload" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' www.google-analytics.comajax.googleapis.com www.google.com google.com gstatic.com www.gstatic.com connectfacebook.net facebook.com;";
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";
    }
```

When I deployed the above it didn't work so I tried adding the same thing below

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;preload" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' www.google-analytics.comajax.googleapis.com www.google.com google.com gstatic.com www.gstatic.com connectfacebook.net facebook.com;";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";
}
```

Again no good and then I tried deploying with both at the same time still no good.

I'm new to Nginx so not sure what the issue is, any help is appreciated. Thanks!